# Generate full SQL script from EF 5 Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

How do I use Entity Framework 5 Code First Migrations to create a full database script from the initial (empty) state to the latest migration?

The blog post at [MSDN Blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) suggests to do this, but it seems to create an empty script:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Generating-Idempotent-Scripts-EF6-onwards

Answer (score 316, accepted):

The API appears to have changed (or at least, it doesn't work for me).

Running the following in the Package Manager Console works as expected:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0
```

Comment: I realise this is the correct answer, but how on earth did you discover that 0 works when the parameter is normally a string?!

Comment: Just trial and error really after trying everything I could think of to trick it into working :)

Comment: Does this create an exact copy of the database? Including the table contents?

Comment: @Multitut: no it'll only do the structure.

Comment: @DaveR there's actually a special `$InitialDatabase` variable that symbolizes that "special initial migration". But here's the trick: `$InitialDatabase` is just an alias for `0` constant!

Comment: How can we script the Seed Data?  :)

Comment: Shows an empty script for me.

Comment: Note: The generated script checks in __MigrationHistory to see if the migrations have already been applied. It does this purely on the name of the migration (does not actually compare schemas). Therefore if the reason you want a full script is to be able to delete the tables and start again you must also delete any items in __MigrationHistory for the context you're using.

Comment: Just in case someone is looking how to do this in EfCore and ended up here like me, the command is: `dotnet ef migrations script`. More on documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#generating-a-sql-script

Comment: using a "0" will revert all the migrations first. Not a good idea if you have data

Comment: really dumb question but where I can find the script after generating it?

Answer (score 59):

For anyone using entity framework **core** ending up here. This is how you do it.

```
# Powershell / Package manager console
Script-Migration

# Cli 
dotnet ef migrations script
```

You can use the `-From` and `-To` parameter to generate an update script to update a database to a specific version.

```
Script-Migration -From 20190101011200_Initial-Migration -To 20190101021200_Migration-2
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#generate-sql-scripts

> There are several options to this command.
>
> The **from** migration should be the last migration applied to the database before running the script. If no migrations have been applied, specify `0` (this is the default).
>
> The **to** migration is the last migration that will be applied to the database after running the script. This defaults to the last migration in your project.
>
> An **idempotent** script can optionally be generated. This script only applies migrations if they haven't already been applied to the database. This is useful if you don't exactly know what the last migration applied to the database was or if you are deploying to multiple databases that may each be at a different migration.

Comment: This works to a point. Once you start changing column names it will start throwing errors, creating a DacPac is a better solution. Especially when you start using Pipelines in CI/CD

Comment: You can omit the timestamp in the migration names and it'll still work.

Answer (score 10):

To add to Matt wilson's answer I had a bunch of code-first entity classes but no database as I hadn't taken a backup.  So I did the following on my Entity Framework project:

Open Package Manager console in Visual Studio and type the following:

```
Enable-Migrations

Add-Migration
```

Give your migration a name such as 'Initial' and then create the migration.  Finally type the following:

```
Update-Database

Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0
```

The final command will create your database tables from your entity classes (provided your entity classes are well formed).

Answer (score 0):

**Case 01:** The following generates a SQL script from a blank database to the latest migration.

In **.Net Cli** type the following.

```
dotnet ef migrations script
```

If you want to do the same in **visual studio package manager console**. Type the following

```
Script-Migration
```

---

**Case 02:** The following generates a SQL script from the given migration to the latest migration.

**In .Net Cli**

```
dotnet ef migrations script AddNewTables
```

**In visual studio package manager console**

```
Script-Migration AddNewTables
```

---

**Case 03:** The following generates a SQL script from the specified from migration to the specified to migration.

**In .Net Cli**

```
dotnet ef migrations script AddNewTables AddAuditTable
```

**In visual studio package manager console**

```
Script-Migration AddNewTables AddAuditTable
```

---

For more details. [Please refer to the link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)