# EF Migrations - straight to final schema

Tags: entity-framework

My schema has evolved over many iterations. I have a set of migrations taking the schema from an empty db to one with dozens of tables and scores of columns.

Along the way there have been several additions of tables, columns and constraints, sometimes followed (in light of experience or new knowledge or changes in the spec) by removal or alterations. Sometimes a table or column name has been re-used or re-purposed.

Now, EF migrations seems perfectly able to run through the sequence creating, altering, dropping, creating again, altering, etc., to get to the latest schema, but it feels wrong. In an extreme case there might be dozens of migrations creating tables followed by dozens more dropping tables until the final schema might be one or two tables (unlikely, I know). An option to go from scratch to just those final tables would feel right.

In my Ruby days with ActiveRecord migrations there was an option to build only the final schema, without stepping through and possibly undoing or redoing work along the way. Of course this meant keeping a complete DDL version of the schema up to date after each migration, but somehow it felt more elegant.

Has anyone done anything similar with Entity Framework?

Comment: depends on the state of the Target schema.  Did you mean a new empty schema. Or the existing prod schema ?

Comment: I'm thinking of the case where you spin up a new database - maybe just as a test or demo, or at that point when you're satisfied that the system ready and you want to create the db on a customer's live server, or maybe jumping direct to version 2.0 for a new customer.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try deleting the `__MigrationHistory` table from your database, removing the `Migrations` folder (backing up your Configuration.cs file), and then enabling migrations again.

Comment: Not sure you got my meaning... I'm OK with the idea of nuking the whole migration trail and starting again to have EF show me the code needed to build a fresh schema based on the current set of models - at least until I've deployed to the first live instance. In the ruby world, ActiveRecord effectively maintains a special single migration Up() method which would empty the db and create everything afresh. This rake task is called as "rake db:schema:load" as an alternative to "rake db:migrate". Migrations are kept, so you could (if you wanted) load the schema and then migrate down 5 steps.

Comment: Yes, in this case you would literally be starting again and creating 1 initial migration which gets you to your current schema, so there would be no way to roll back down migrations. If you're not happy with 1 migration, then you could manually tidy up your existing migration class files instead.

Answer (score 0):

Then start here for PM commands to build scripts

[Generate full SQL script from EF 5 Code First Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939404/generate-full-sql-script-from-ef-5-code-first-migrations)

from code, there is an option on the ObjectContext not directly on DbContext

```
 string script = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
```

Of course Automated Migrations would work if you dont need to see the magic and have altered the generated scripts.

```
   Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDbContext,
                           YourMigrationConfiguration>()
   Context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

And if it is an EmptyDb Schema, EF will do that for free.

```
  Context.Database.Initialize(true);
```