# Generate Database from model creates empty edmx sql script

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first

I am playing around with Code first, have created my entities and am now trying to generate a database from the model. I have gone through the wizard, successfully connected to the server, selected the name of the new database and exited. An edmx.sql script is automatically generated for me to run, except it's empty when I open it and it massively slows down VS 2010 to the point that I have to kill the process.

When I look in the server the database has been created (as expected since the wizard asked me to create it) but there are not tables in it (obviously because I haven't run the script).

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: did you check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939404/generate-full-sql-script-from-ef-5-code-first-migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused this. Apparently the SP1 upgrade on VS2010 torches this sort of thing. The following files need to be re-installed manually from the DVD:

DACFramework_enu.msi

DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi

TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi

Now I can see the full script, ran it, sorted!