# Manually applying migrations in Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core to access a database.  I'd like to modify the database.  I don't want to use the EF tool to manage migrations.  I want to do it myself.

In this instance I know that my database is old and I need to modify it.  I want to set up the migration with something like this:

```
MigrationBuilder myMigration = new("SQLite");
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "NewField",
    table: "MyTable",
    type: "INTEGER",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 0);
```

And then I want to apply the migration. I would imagine something like:

```
db.Database.ApplyMigration(myMigration);
```

Does anything like this exist? `MigrationBuilder` doesn't come with much documentation except to point to using the EF tool to manage migrations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate full SQL script from EF 5 Code First Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939404/generate-full-sql-script-from-ef-5-code-first-migrations)

Answer (score -1):

you can still achieve this by directly executing SQL commands. But that directly modifying the database in this way bypasses the benefits of using EF Core migrations, such as versioning and the ability to easily roll back changes.

```
var migrationSql = @"ALTER TABLE MyTable
                     ADD COLUMN NewField INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;"

dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(migrationSql);
```

Comment: How is "just skip doing migrations" an answer to "how do I do migrations"?  There are manual ways to do it.